# I need a python function to extract an element from array of arbitrary depth

Tags: python, arrays, keyerror

I need to process elements in an array in a python function - I want to assign a default value if the element doesn't exist. But the element to be processed may be of arbitrary depth in the array.  ie, sometimes I need to do this:

```
x=myFunc(myArray,"element","here")
```

but sometimes it's like this:

```
x=myFunc(myArray,"deeper","element","here")
```

or even

```
x=myFunc(myArray,"even","deeper""element","here")
```

So to achieve this I've written my terribly inefficient function **myFunc**

```
def myFunc(myDict,*args):
    if len(args) == 2 :
        try:
            returnValue=myDict[args[0]][args[1]]
        except KeyError:
            returnValue="Some default value"
    elif len(args) == 3 :
        try:
            returnValue=myDict[args[0]][args[1]][args[2]]
        except KeyError:
            returnValue="Some default value"
    elif len(args) == 4 :
        try:
            returnValue=myDict[args[0]][args[1]][args[2]][args[3]]
        except KeyError:
            returnValue="Some default value"
    return returnValue
```

Yes, I know I **could** assign the value directly to x and put the **except KeyError:** around those assignments, but of course I've stripped the example down to simplify it.

I know there has to be a better way of extracting an element from array of arbitrary depth - if I could change **args** from ("list","of","elements") into ["list"]["of"]["elements"] I think I'd have it.

Any ideas?

Here's my sample test using the above:

```
def main():
    myDict = {
      "first": {
        "second1": "2",
        "second2": "22",
        "deeper": {
          "third1": "3",
          "third2": "33"
        }
      }
    }

    x=myFunc(myDict,"first","second1")
    print "x should be 2. And x is...",x
    x=myFunc(myDict,"first","deeper","third2")
    print "x should be 33. And x is...",x
    x=myFunc(myDict,"first","hopefullyGetDefaultReturned")
    print "x should be 'Some default value'.  And x is...",x


main()
```

Comment: try using recursion?

Comment: That doesn't sound like an array.

Comment: @user2357112 - mea culpa - it's a dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

A loop:

```
def get_by_path(value, *path):
    for key in path:
        value = value[key]

    return value
```

With default:

```
def get_or_default(value, default, *path):
    try:
        return get_by_path(value, *path)
    except KeyError:
        return default
```

Comment: Nailed it. Thank you. Took me a while to figure out exactly what `value = value[key]` was doing, but of course it was doing exactly what I needed it to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interactive demonstration of one possible approach:

```
bash-3.2$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 29 2016, 14:57:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def val(a,*p):
...     for i in p: a = a[i]
...     return a
... 
>>> x = [1,[2,3,[4,5,6,7]]]
>>> val(x,1)
[2, 3, [4, 5, 6, 7]]
>>> val(x,1,2)
[4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> val(x,1,2,3)
7
>>>
```